# Regular Expression To Match Multiple "-" occurances in a Filename

Tags: regex, grep

I am Trying to Construct a Regular Expression to Find File names Which have Multiple - Occurrences. I Mainly need this Regular Expression to ID Tag MP3 Files Which are in a Format  - .

The Problem is that Some artists in my Collection have a - in their name. 
Hence I need to Construct a Regular Expression which will list all those File names which have Multiple - in their File name ( One for the Artist Name, and the other that act as a separator between the Artist and the Title [ Such as Ar-tist - Title ), to Manually Tag Them.

So far I managed to Extract File names with a Single - Using the Regular Expression

```
*-*
```

What I need Now is a Regular Expression to Match two Literal -.

Thank you,
Andrew Borg

Comment: That's not a regex. It might be a file glob, which is something else.

Comment: Argh Yes you are Right, How I did not Think of That.

Comment: Can you add some examples of such file names. `*-*-*` should work otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
([^-]*-){2}
```

Now, notice `*-*` is not working as you thing it is. It does not seem to be well formed, as `*` is a regex quantifier that means "zero or more times", e.g., `a*` (where `a` is a valid expression) means "`a` zero or more times"

Even if you tool accepts it, it will also match `"------"`.

Comment: Well done, Did the Job Nicely. I Guess I have to research more On Regular Expressions when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

The stackoverflow comment parser breaks my example.

But can't you just use `*-*-*`

Comment: Ohh, thanks :) I though the comment field was very limited. Will use backticks next time. Now it turned my answer into --* or something

Comment: Still the Same Result, Tried it Already. I think It's because it is a File Glob like Pguardiario pointed out ;)

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? Your question isn't totally clear. Try with using -- before your glob. That will tell grep not do parameter check on everything after the --. Or you could use regex like syntax with -E